# Efficiently concatenate two strings from tuples in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, performance

I want to concatenate the two string elements in a list of tuples

I have this:

```
mylist = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h')]
myanswer = []

for tup1 in mylist:
   myanswer.append(tup1[0] + tup[1])
```

It's working but is there any easy way to do this? My real list has around 1000 items and I don't think a `for` loop is the most efficient way.

Expected output:

```
myanswer = ["ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"]
```

Comment: Well, your question was confusing. You claimed it wasn't working, then correct it to working code and are asking for a more efficient way to do this. You do want to make sure you are asking the question correctly and clearly, with an example that is actually valid Python code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension, and for just two elements, I'd use tuple unpacking and concatenation:

```
myanswer = [s1 + s2 for s1, s2 in mylist]
```

Another option is to use a [formatted string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
myanswer = [f"{s1}{s2}" for s1, s2 in mylist]
```

Both are reasonably fast:

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> from string import ascii_letters
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> testdata = [(choice(ascii_letters), choice(ascii_letters)) for _ in range(10000)]
>>> count, total = Timer('[f"{s1}{s2}" for s1, s2 in mylist]', 'from __main__ import testdata as mylist').autorange()
>>> print(f"List comp with f-string, 10k elements: {total / count * 1000000:7.2f} microseconds")
List comp with f-string, 10k elements: 1249.37 microseconds
>>> count, total = Timer('[s1 + s2 for s1, s2 in mylist]', 'from __main__ import testdata as mylist').autorange()
>>> print(f"List comp with concatenation, 10k elements: {total / count * 1000000:6.2f} microseconds")
List comp with concatenation, 10k elements: 1061.89 microseconds
```

Concatenation wins out here.

A list comprehension removes the need to look up the list object and its `.append()` method each time in a loop, see [What is the advantage of a list comprehension over a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341775/what-is-the-advantage-of-a-list-comprehension-over-a-for-loop/16341841#16341841)

Formatted string literals where introduced in Python 3.6, and are easily the fastest way of composing strings with interpolated elements (even though they [didn't start out that way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365311/why-are-literal-formatted-strings-so-slow-in-python-3-6-alpha-now-fixed-in-3-6)).

I also tried out [`itertools.starmap()`] with [`operator.add()`] and [`str.join()`], but this doesn't appear to be competitive:

```
>>> count, total = Timer('list(starmap(add, mylist))', 'from __main__ import testdata as mylist; from itertools import starmap; from operator import add').autorange()
>>> print(f"itertools.starmap and operator.add, 10k elements: {total / count * 1000000:6.2f} microseconds")
itertools.starmap and operator.add, 10k elements: 1275.02 microseconds
>>> count, total = Timer('list(starmap(str.join, mylist))', 'from __main__ import testdata as mylist; from itertools import starmap').autorange()
>>> print(f"itertools.starmap and str.join, 10k elements: {total / count * 1000000:6.2f} microseconds")
itertools.starmap and str.join, 10k elements: 1564.79 microseconds
```

It does improve with more elements; by 1 million elements, `map(starmap(add, largelist))` is winning by a small margin (133ms vs 140ms for a list comprehension with concatenation).